# How to parse shell script output in maven

Tags: bash, maven, maven-3

I run a unixODBC installation script in a maven pom.xml file and it has the following output.

> Run the command 'cd /tmp/unixODBC.30048.28312.21379/unixODBC-2.3.0; make install' to install the driver manager.

How do I capture the text inside the '' above, e.g., `cd /tmp/unixODBC.30048.28312.21379/unixODBC-2.3.0; make install`, and then execute it? The /tmp/unixODBC* directory name changes everytime.

Comment: How do you run that *installation script*? What's the order of events here?

Comment: I run it inside a pom.xml file using the the bash-maven plugin https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/bash-maven-plugin.

Comment: If you are already using the bash-maven plugin, then you should just write another bash script that captures that output with a regex and executes the command. Maven doesn't have any magic plugin that will do that for you here.

Comment: What do you currently have in the `<script></script>` tag?

Comment: <script>./build_dm.sh --accept-warning | tee out.txt</script> as someone suggested I piped the output into a text file. Now how so sed the text between the ' ' in my original post?

Answer (score 0):

you could pipe your maven output to

```
mvn ...|grep -oP "(?<=')[^']*(?=')"|sh
```

without the ending `|sh` you  could check if the captured the commands chain correct.